# What are the control keys available when working in a text field?

Tags: keyboard, text-editor, emacs, macvim

I know that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> will move to me to the end of a line, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> to the start.

I also know that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> will move down a line.

What other <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-key combinations are there?

Is it possible to move up a line?

How about, most desirable for me, is there something to move back and forth a word at a time?

I realize that I can do these things in emacs, or with an alternate set of keys in vi, but that's not what I am interested in.

If I am writing a question on one of the stackexchange sites or on a wiki, vi and emacs are not in play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default key bindings are stored in `/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict`. You can use `plutil` to convert the file to an XML format, like so:

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o StandardKeyBinding.xml  /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict
```

Or, if you have Xcode or Property List Editor, you can open it there.

In addition, you can add your own bindings system-wide to `/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`, or per-user to `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`.

[This page](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/System%20Bindings.html) has a nice overview of bindings. I've grown particularly fond of **Transpose** (<kbd>⌃</kbd>-T), which swaps the two letters to the left and right of your cursor, fixing my most common kind of typo quickly.

In addition, there are various additional tricks using the <kbd>⌥</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> keys:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> move to the beginning or end of the *line*. Add <kbd>⇧</kbd> to select everything in between.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> move to the beginning or end of the *document*. Add <kbd>⇧</kbd> to select everything in between.
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> move to the beginning or end of the *word*, or between multiple words. Add <kbd>⇧</kbd> to select everything in between.
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> move to the beginning or end of the *paragraph*. Add <kbd>⇧</kbd> to select everything in between.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> and the cursor <kbd>← / →</kbd> keys to move back and forth whole words at a time, taking you to either the beginning or end of the word depending on the direction you choose.

Using <kbd>shift</kbd> also allows you to highlight text as you pass over it.

Using the same combinations with <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd> does the same within paragraphs.